# I can login using su in other accounts, but not using login screen

Tags: 18.04, login, password, login-screen, su

When I try to login to my administrative account using Ubuntu's login screen, I cannot. However, I can access other accounts and log in to them. Additionally, I can login to my account using `su` command in one of the standard accounts by Terminal.

For instance, I've logged in to someone's account and I'm questioning from there. Now, I can open Terminal, run `su machitgarha`, enter the right password and login to my account. However, with that true password, there is no chance for logging in to my account using login screen.

Could someone help me please? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I didn't think it was as just simple as it! I changed my password from Settings app (User settings), and now I can log in to my account. However, I guess because I moved some files and directories (including `.profile`, `.config` and `.cache`) somewhere as a backup (e.g., `.profile.back`), my desktop screen returned to its default state.